# What is this JPA error and how to fix it?

Tags: jpa

My TableX has reference to TableY.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "idTableY", referencedColumnName = "idTableY")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private TableY idTableY;
```

and I get this error.

```
<openjpa-2.0.0-r422266:935683 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException 
"com.mycompany.entities.TableX.idTableY" has columns with targets, but OpenJPA does not support any joins on this mapping in this context.
```

Table Y has this code:

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idTableY")
    private Collection<TableX> tableXCollection;
```

This generated eclipse-link code is 100% normal ( all other entities/tables with similar code have no problems).

But a couple of these are giving such errors. Any idea why?

Comment: what is the column name of tableY that is referencing tableX??

Comment: persistence.xml has nothing on it except the fully class name of the entities, and connectionstring

Comment: Do you have both entities listed in persistence.xml?

Comment: yes.. I solved the problem using subqueries. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove the `@JoinColumn` definition it is unnecessary. The join column containing foreign key is generated automatically. Entity is not a table those are two different things. Entity is class mapped on db table(s).

Comment: Yes I realize entity isn't a table (sorry).  Thanks for the joincolumn tips

Answer (score 5):

I got this exact error but for me the fix was to add TableY to the list of classes in the persistence unit in my persistence.xml.
For me TableY was a brand new entity.
I use the @JoinColumn on it and it works fine.

Comment: I just found this answer useful, again! =P

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class to the *persistence.xml* file.
Example:

```
<class> com.mycompany.entities.TableX</class>
<class> com.mycompany.entities.TableY</class>
```